# Conflicting Types for puncte

Tags: c, types

```
int main()
{scanf("%d",&n);
float *puncte;

puncte=(float*)malloc(n*sizeof(float));
printf("\nSIZEOF PUNCTE: \n%d",sizeof(puncte));

struct varfuri{
float x; float y;
}puncte[sizeof(puncte)-1];

return 0;}
```

Why do I get this error?

Error: conflicting types for 'puncte'|

Comment: you've got it defined first as `float` and then as `struct`. The message is clear.

Comment: Then how should i define it?

Comment: genius: are you just being ironic?

Comment: I have to use create the vector this struct uses with dinamic allocation

Comment: Well you should be one, right :D ?

Comment: no need to be to see that your code is _very_ wrong. But I don't understand what you want to do: `struct varfuri{
float x; float y;
}puncte[sizeof(puncte)-1];` is wrong because `puncte` is already a `float`. You see what your mistake is?

Comment: I got to scanf n points in cartesian system. I have to memorate those points into a vector(that must be constructed with dynamic allocation), of this struct type. In the struct i got the X coordonate, and also the Y coordonates of each point.

Comment: Yes i understand :) But how should i do then ?

Comment: `struct varfuri{ float x; float y; }`, then create an array of `varfuri` items using malloc, not `puncte`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  Consider an opening brace '{' and a closing brace '}' to be separate statement.  2) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'. unindent before every closing brace '}',  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces as that is visible even with variable width fonts.

Comment: the operator `sizeof()` know nothing about what a pointer points to.  All it knows is a pointer is x bytes long (4 on a 32 bit architecture)

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling any of the heap memory allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned type from these functions is `void*` so can be assigned to any other pointer.  Casting the returned type just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.

Answer (score 1):

the following code:

1. incorporates the question comments
2. cleanly compiles
3. demonstrates how to allocate many instances of a struct in an array
4. demonstrates how to handle the errors
5. the operator `sizeof()` returns a `size_t` not an `int` so all references are modified accordingly

and now the code

```
#include <stdio.h>  // scanf(), perror()
#include <stdlib.h> // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE, malloc()

struct varfuri
{
    float x; 
    float y;
};

int main( void )
{
    size_t numPoints;

    if( 1 != scanf("%lu",&numPoints) )
    {
        perror( "scanf failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, scanf successful


    struct varfuri *puncte = malloc(numPoints * sizeof( struct varfuri ));
    if( NULL == puncte )
    {
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    // the following, on a 32 bit architecture, will return 4
    printf("\nSIZEOF PUNCTE: \n%lu",sizeof(puncte));

    //return 0;  not needed when the returned value from `main()` is 0
} // end function: main
```